# How to add volume shadow copy service to WINPE

Tags: service, registry, winpe

I am making self WinPE using Windows AIK (Windows Automated Installation Kit).
I added many packages using DSIM command.
But I can not add Volume Shadow Copy service.

I found same issue [here](http://forum.sanbarrow.com/viewtopic.php?f=85&t=49) and [here](http://reboot.pro/topic/14459-add-vss-shadow-copy-service-to-winpe-3/page-2)
But I don't understand what to do.

Please help me.

Comment: Why would you ever need shadow copy service when running in WinPE? There are no open files from running applications, so you should have open access to everything on the system. This is one of the benefits of running in WinPE.

Comment: I want to restore some system files at WinPE and without vss service it can not be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem using Windows Recovery PE Image.

I mounted windows recovery disk using diskpart and extracted WinRE.wim.

That wim file has vss service running and i solved this problem.

Thank you.